# Is it better to develop for 1366x768 nowadays?

Tags: responsive-design, resolution, screen-resolution

I need to develop a website and the website need to be responsive. I haven't developd a site since 2011. I always developed with `960px`, but now I already did some Google search now and I view some statistics that say that nowadays the resolution most used is `1366x768`. So maybe its better develop for `1366x768`? Whats your opinion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [StatCount](http://gs.statcounter.com/#resolution-na-monthly-201302-201402) to give you a idea how much market are you losing (the link points to screen resolution statistics for North America in the last year period).

First you can try to support all screen resolutions you can.
Now, how much work do you need to add support for lower resolutions and how that ill affect your site? It depends a lot on what do you want and how do you develop your sites.

It's a trade off and only you can tell if you need to support that resolution or if it a waste of time and money.

Comment: A requirement of the job is the site adapt to all devices, but as I'm not too exprient in responsive design, I'm having some difficulties to choose the best approach for the job I have to do. I've been to analyze the website you sent me, and develop with 1366 * 768 dont seems good, because I am losing many people.  Maybe I´ll continue with my olds 960px and use CSS3 Media Queries to adapt the site to other resolutions. Thanks for your attention :)